# Google Drive API V3

Tags: model-view-controller, google-drive-api

I am not able to get data from google drive like thumbnail link, download etc in Asp.Net MVC when i am using V3 api but these data comes in V2 verson.

Can any one help me.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  1. Why are you not able to get this information.  2.  what have you tried? 3. are you seeing any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention this code
//ds is DriverService
`FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = ds.Files.List();
listRequest.Fields = "files(*)";`

//files(*) will populate all fields, so you'll get what you want.